# matrix derivative w.r.t a scalar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

How the following derivative can be calculated?

$\displaystyle\frac{d}{d\lambda}A\left(\lambda\ I+A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T$

where $A$ is a rectangular matrix and $\lambda$ is a scalar.

Comment: If the requirements are fullfiled, you could use Neumann series and differentiate term wise.

Comment: @tired thanks but how about the case when we have multiple terms like $A\left(\lambda\ I+A^TA\right)^{-1}A^TA\left(\lambda\ I+A^TA\right)^{-1}A^T$, can we use somethin like chain rule? I guess not

Comment: yes, but you have to consider the non commutativity of the matrices. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(\lambda)=-A(\lambda I+A^TA)^{-2}A^T$.